# Entity Framework 6 Extend migration class to map new values

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-6

I used to have a table like that:

```
[Table("Users")]
internal class DbUser
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public DbAccountStatusEnum AccountStatus { get; set; }
}
```

With a relation to EnumTable like this one:

```
[Table("AccountStatuses")]
internal sealed class DbAccountStatusEnum : DbEnumBase<AccountStatusEnum>
{
    public DbAccountStatusEnum(AccountStatusEnum @enum)
    {
        Id = (int)@enum;
        Name = @enum.ToString();
        Description = @enum.GetEnumDescription();
    }        
}
```

That stored Enum itself with its' description. Enum like this one:

```
[Flags]
public enum AccountStatusEnum
{
    [Description("Non-active Account")]
    Disabled = 0,
    [Description("Active Account")]
    Active = 1,
    [Description("Blocked Account")]
    Blocked = 2,
    [Description("Removed Account")]
    Removed = 4,
    [Description("Additional action required for account to be active")]
    Incomplete = 8
}
```

It was stored through a relation inside Users' table to Enum "Id". I am during refactor and I have totally wiped out that second table and gone for single column inside User's table. Like this one:

```
[Table("Users")]
internal class DbUser
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public AccountStatusEnum AccountStatus { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that Enum flag starts with 0, new one starts with 1 (code below) and my question is: **how do I map inside an EF6 migration old Enum "Id" to new simple int Enum leaving the AccountStatus of a user the same as before?**

```
    [Flags]
public enum AccountStatusEnum
{
    [Description("Non-active Account")]
    Disabled = 1,
    [Description("Active Account")]
    Active = 2,
    [Description("Blocked Account")]
    Blocked = 4,
    [Description("Removed Account")]
    Removed = 8,
    [Description("Additional action required for account to be active")]
    Incomplete = 16
}
```

Comment: The easy way is to do it in 2 steps. Add the new field and translate in 1st migration. Then remove and rename in the 2nd migration.

Comment: But how should I translate it? Iterate over column values inside a migration? If yes, how?

Comment: No, use a SqlCommand like: `Sql("UPDATE dbUser SET NewValue  =  1 WHERE OldValue = 0");` then `Sql("UPDATE dbUser SET New  =  Old * 2 WHERE OldValue > 0 AND NewValue IS NULL");` Run this after you add the column.

Comment: Great, I was hoping on avoiding SQL Statement but your answer helps me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use a SqlCommand like: `Sql("UPDATE dbUser SET NewValue = 1 WHERE OldValue = 0");` then `Sql("UPDATE dbUser SET New = Old * 2 WHERE OldValue > 0 AND NewValue IS NULL");` Run this after you add the column

Yes, indeed it's a good answer for anyone who came across this. From me I would add

```
DropForeignKey("dbo.Users", "AccountStatus_Id", "dbo.AccountStatuses");
DropIndex("dbo.Users", new[] { "AccountStatus_Id" });
```

before performing Update and after adding a column.